# Change Font size on change of range slider by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to dynamically change css property values by jQuery.But it is not changing dynamically.

### Here is the codes

```
<input type="range" class="prinz-rs__range" name="rangeInputName" value="20" 
 min="10" max="100" oninput='dynamicDisplayChange(this, "head_1", "33");' />
 <h3 data-id="focused_post_font_size_phsm2">hello there</h3>
```

### Here is javascript

```
function dynamicDisplayChange(elem, target, id){
  if( 'head_1' == target  ){
    $('h3[data-id="focused_post_font_size_phsm2"]')
         .css('font-size', elem.value);
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ssg17va7/1/

Comment: The issue is because your fiddle isn't configured correctly. Use JS, not JS1.7, and use a Load Type of <head>. Then you need to put a unit on the `font-size`. In this updated version I used `px`: https://jsfiddle.net/ssg17va7/2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  
wow! thats great..But when i use in my script? what in case of <head>?